# .htaccess mod_rewrite on specific host

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite

This is just a quick question, and I apologise if this has been asked before, however I'm not that good with Apache.

I have a url called: http://beta.example.com

I would like Apache to rewrite this to:

http://www.example.com/beta

The url should only rewrite when 'beta.' is used, and the HTTP_HOST structure should be preserved.

Many Regards,

Anderas

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/beta/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/beta/$1 [R=301,L]
```

*Redirects*

```
https://beta.example.com => https://www.example.com/beta/
http://beta.example.com/somepage.php => http://www.example.com/beta/somepage.php
```

Comment: No, it won't. To preserve http/https you'll have to have two set of rules. Check update.